# Envio de e-mail com função mail

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Tenho um site na localweb, e a primeira pergunta é: consigo enviar e-mail sem autenticação? Bom pelo jeito eu acho que não, pois apesar de aparecer escrito "O seu email foi enviado com sucesso!" não recebo o e-mail.
Segunda pergunta, para autenticar o envio, seja com a função mail ou PHPmailer é necessário contratar algum plano desse: http://migre.me/vT5pZ ?

Comment: O PHPMailer é uma classe pronta para envio das mensagens utilizando autenticação no servidor de e-mails de seu domínio muito utilizado por todo o mundo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.dominio.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP ou
//$mail->Host = "mail.seudominio.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP ou
//$mail->Host = "localhost"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP
$mail->Username = 'seumail@dominio.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'senha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP

// Define o remetente
$mail->From = "seumail@dominio.com"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Fulano de Tal"; // Seu nome

// Define os destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress('destinatario1@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário');
//$mail->AddAddress('destinatario2@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário');
//$mail->AddCC('destinatario3@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário'); // Copia
//$mail->AddBCC('destinatario4@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário'); // Cópia Oculta

// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
$mail->Subject  = "Mensagem Teste"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = 'Este é o corpo da mensagem, blablabla..... ';

// Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
if ($enviado) {
echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
echo "Informações do erro:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

//arquivos necessários: class.phpmailer.php - class.smtp.php
//pode pegar em https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
```

Comment: arquivos necessários: class.phpmailer.php -  class.smtp.php - class.smtp.php em https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer