# confirmação de cadastro via e-mail

Tags: php, email, validação

Estou montando um sistema de cadastro e só falta a parte da confirmação no email para terminar e não estou conseguindo fazer essa parte. Já pesquisei tutoriais no youtube e tentei aplicá-los ao meu código, só que não funciona, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['cadastrar']) && $_POST ['cadastrar'] == "register")
{
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pais = $_POST['pais'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $rsenha = $_POST['rsenha'];
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    if(empty($nome) || empty($sobrenome) || empty($data) || empty($cpf) || empty($email) ||  empty($pais) || empty($estado) || empty($login) || empty($senha) || empty($rsenha) || ($cpf_enviado == false) || (@$emailvalida == false))

        {

        }else{
            $query = "SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE login = '$login'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $conta = mysql_num_rows($result);
            $busca = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            if($conta > 0){
                echo '<div id="preencha" style="width:200px; position:relative; left:580px; top:-30px; color:#fff; font-size:15px; ">Usuário já cadastrado!</div>   ';
            }else{
                $cadastrar = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, data, cpf, email, pais, estado, login, senha, rsenha, image)
                             VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$data', '$cpf', '$email', '$pais', '$estado', '$login', '$senha', '$rsenha', '$image')";
                if(mysql_query($cadastrar))
                {
                    $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
                    $_SESSION['sobrenome'] = $sobrenome;
                    $_SESSION['data'] = $data;
                    $_SESSION['cpf'] = $cpf;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['pais'] = $pais;
                    $_SESSION['estado'] = $estado;
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
                    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;    
                    $_SESSION['rsenha'] = $rsenha;
                    $_SESSION['image'] = $image;

                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.setTimeout(\"location.href='cadastroRealizado.php';\");</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<div id="preencha" style="width:200px; position:relative; left:580px; top:-30px; color:#fff; font-size:15px; ">Erro ao cadastrar!</div>';
                }

                $conexaoemail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE nome = '$nome'");
                $resultado = mysql_fetch_array($conexaoemail);
                $id = $resultado['id'];

                $assunto = "Ative sua conta";
                $mensagem = "Ative sua conta clicando no link:";
                $headers = "equipe.weedinfo@gmail.com";
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                mail($email, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);

            }
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Qual é o problema que está enfrentando? Sua aplicação exibe algum erro quando o código é executado?

Comment: No caso do problema, eu segui este tutorial simples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqddjTQjJXA&t=906s

Quando chega na hora de enviar o email ele não envia.

Comment: Se tiver um tutorial em video ou em instruções melhor, por favor me passa, estou precisando muito e quero aprender a fazer isso.

Comment: Se o problema é no no código do envio de email, tenta usar o PHPMailer http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177812/envio-de-e-mail-com-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mail/177832#177832

Comment: Veja isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40858/como-enviar-e-mail-do-localhost-usando-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mail-do-php/40861#40861

Comment: primeiramente você precisa do seguinte, seu servidor SMTP está ativo e autenticado com seu servidor pop? exemplo, você pode tentar o mailgun antes de enviar para o servidor online, e no caso, se funcionar com mailgun pode ser seu servidor.

Comment: Pense em usar algum framework que poderá lhe auxiliar muito neste ponto, um que torna muito fácil o envio de e-mails é o Laravel

Answer (score 1):

Eu retirei esse bom exemplo do site oficial do PHP:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Esse segundo exemplo é mais elegante:

```
<?php
// Multiple recipients
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com'; // note the comma

// Subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// Message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johny</td><td>10th</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Fonte:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Esta resposta está correta do lado do PHP, apenas não se deve esquecer que deve haver um servidor de e-mail rodando no mesmo servidor para funciona. PHP não manda e-mail diretamente ao destino, é preciso haver um servidor de e-mail que efetivamente entregue. Além do que, é problemático entregar e-mails diretamente ao destino hoje em dia devido aos controles anti-spam. O ideal é contratar uma conta num serviço de e-mail para usar como smarthost, o que implica em configurar direito o servidor de e-mail.

Answer (score -1):

Esqueça a função mail, utilize o PHPMailer 
[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

segue exemplo

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug =2;// 0,1 ou 2
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "senha";
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setFrom('email_origem@email.com', 'Informativo');
$mail->addAddress('email1@email.com', 'algum texto');
$mail->addAddress('email2@email.com', 'algum texto');
$mail->addAddress('email3@email.com', 'algum texto');
$mail->Subject = 'assunto do email';

$mensagem = 'Teste teste teste ';
$mensagem .= 'outro teste';

$mail->msgHTML($mensagem);

$mail->AltBody = 'Caso você esteja lendo essa mensagem é provável que seu cliente de email não tenha suporte a HTML';
if (!$mail->send()){
    echo "email NÃO enviado";
}else {
    echo "email enviado com sucesso";
}
```

Comment: Por qual motivo, se a própria biblioteca PHPMailer utiliza a função `mail`?

Comment: na minha opinião: tratamento de erros mais elaborado, anexação de documentos de forma simples, inclusão de diversos emails de forma mais fácil

Comment: Então coloque isso na sua resposta para melhorá-la e criar, de fato, uma resposta.

Comment: editei minha resposta, blz?